# Stacked images after loading of the page in isotope

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, jquery-isotope

I have page with images and a filter based on `isotope` technology. 
Problem is, that after loading of the page the images are stacked.
Just after use of the filter (option `a`, `b` ,`c`), the images unstack as are intended to be.

```
$(function() {
    var grid = $('#portfolio .grid').isotope({
        itemSelector: '.work',
        layoutMode: 'fitRows'
    });

    $('#portfolio .filter').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
        var el = $(this);

        grid.isotope({
            filter: el.data('filter')
        });

        el.addClass('checked').siblings().removeClass('checked');
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/martinrusina/eLf4ynna/12/).

To simulate first load hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> in Firefox or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> on Mac.

I tried this fix with [link](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout.html#imagesloaded). Images are not stacked, but now filter is broken.

```
$(function() {
    var grid = $('#portfolio .grid').isotope({
        itemSelector: '.work',
        layoutMode: 'fitRows'
    });

    // recommendation found at isotope.metafizzy.co/layout.html#imagesloaded
    $grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
        $grid.isotope('layout');
    });

    $('#portfolio .filter').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
        var el = $(this);

        grid.isotope({
            filter: el.data('filter')
        });

        el.addClass('checked').siblings().removeClass('checked');
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/martinrusina/eLf4ynna/13/).

How can I remove stacked images and have filter that works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 issues with your second jsfiddle:

```
        $(function() {
            var grid = $('#portfolio .grid').isotope({
                itemSelector: '.work',
                layoutMode: 'fitRows'
            });

            // recommendation found at isotope.metafizzy.co/layout.html#imagesloaded
            $grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
                $grid.isotope('layout');
            });

            $('#portfolio .filter').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
                var el = $(this);

                grid.isotope({
                    filter: el.data('filter')
                });

                el.addClass('checked').siblings().removeClass('checked');
            });
        });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/martinrusina/eLf4ynna/13/

Firstly, $grid is not defined. You defined grid not $grid.

Secondly, you have not included the imagesLoaded library to work with isotope, so imagesLoaded is also undefined.

Here is a working version which includes the library and uses grid instead of $grid:

```
// Includes https://unpkg.com/imagesloaded@4.1.1/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js

        $(function() {
            var grid = $('#portfolio .grid').isotope({
                itemSelector: '.work',
                layoutMode: 'fitRows'
            });

            // Updates grid after each image being loaded
            //grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
            //  grid.isotope('layout');
            //});

            // updates grid after all images are loaded.
            grid.imagesLoaded( function() {
              grid.isotope('layout');
            });

            $('#portfolio .filter').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
                var el = $(this);

                grid.isotope({
                    filter: el.data('filter')
                });

                el.addClass('checked').siblings().removeClass('checked');
            });
        });
```

[Working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awinhayden/1gg0t5zm/1/)